# Test syntax of at command time argument

Tags: linux, bash, at-job

I would like to test an at time argument *before* running the at command. The use case is that I would like to run the at command on a different computer at a different time, so I want to first store the at argument, which means I want to check it when it is first entered.

Example is before:

```
$ atarg1="now+7mintes"
# I would like to check the above *before* running this
$ at $atarg1 <<< "echo hi there"
syntax error. Last token seen: t
Garbled time
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always remove the job from the queue if it succeeds.  This obviously has a race condition - in the unlikely event that the command executes from the queue between submitting and removing it, you will run a command needlessly.  Running `true` when you didn't want to has very low impact, though.

```
if success=$(at "$atarg" <<<true); then
    sed 's/^job \([1-9][0-9]*\) at .*/\1/' <<<"$success" | xargs atrm
    exit 0
else
    exit $?
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try testing the time on GNU `date`.  Note that this fails:

```
$ atarg="now+7mintes"
$ date -d "$atarg" >/dev/null 2>&1 || echo "Bad time"
Bad time
```

while this succeeds:

```
$ atarg="now+7minutes"
$ date -d "$atarg" >/dev/null 2>&1 || echo "Bad time"
```

In other words, when `date -d` is given a bad argument, `date` exits with a nonzero return code.  This allows you to test under bash whether the date is good, at least as far as `date` accepting it.

I have not found any documentation to indicate that `at` and `date` use the same code to interpret dates.   So, this approach has no guarantee.

#### Problem

It turns out that `date` is more flexible about its time format than `at`.  As XuWang points out, `date` accepts `18minutes` as shorthand for `now + 18minutes` but `at` does not:

```
$ date -d "18minutes"
Fri May 27 15:30:59 PDT 2016
$ echo true | at "18minutes"
syntax error. Last token seen: minutes
Garbled time
```

Comment: Thank you, this works good but not great. For example, date understands "18minutes" but at does not, at needs now+18minutes.

Comment: XuWang, I see.  I get the same results.  I hope that @triplee's answer works for you.